# Is there really any issue learning .net c#,asp with version 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner and I am very confused about the.net version so please let me know if is there any issue learning concepts of c#.net and asp.net with version 3.5 and 4.0 and if companies are working on it or not and if these all concepts are outdated or not. please help me I got stuck here can I learn from this and work with the organization or not?

Comment: only because those are old versions doesn't make them obsolete or in any way bad. There are many companies that still use .NET 3.5. You can of course use them, but chances are in newer versions you can do some things better.

Comment: Is there any *point* learning a completely unsupported framework? The oldest supported ASP.NET version is 4.6.2 which is *very* different. There was no MVC, Web API or Razor Pages in 3.5. No async either

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally? No; however, with the age of these tools, it becomes increasingly hard to

1. get the tooling working
2. get good examples that work
3. get help
4. get up-to-date auxiliary libraries to help you work

(and of course it is Windows only)

3.5 SP1 was 2008; in software terms, that's pretty ancient. Is there a market? Sure: some companies (for various reasons) have not or can not migrate to more recent technologies. But for *learning*? I'd probably say "use .NET 7" as the default - it'll solve all of the points above.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that MVC, Web API, Razor Pages, async all came afterwards.

Comment: can i learn the new versions' new concepts while working with the 3.5 version? and how many changes could be in the all-new versions?

Comment: @AnjaliJoshi "how much could change in .NET in 14 years?" - a lot; like *a real lot*; the core stays the same, obviously, but...

Comment: @MarcGravell: but asp.net and c#.net `s fundamentals will be the same in the all-new versions or not and can I start learning all the fundamentals from .net 3.5  and start work or not?

Comment: @AnjaliJoshi .NET 3.5 is part of .NET Framework; .NET 5 / 6 / 7 are ".NET Core" - so yes some fundamentals still apply, but they are *entirely different runtimes*; there was a hard break between .NET Framework (which goes to 4.8) and .NET Core (etc); this is true of asp.net too; "asp.net" and "asp.net core"; very similar yet also different; if I was starting, I'd start with "now" rather than "14 years ago"